# How do you count sp3 hybridized configuration electrons for methane?

Tags: bond, orbitals

I've been reviewing my organic chemistry and upon reviewing sp3 hybridization have become confused.

For methane CH4, the electron clouds rearrange into sp3 hybridization configurations of 1s2 2sp3 2sp3 2sp3 2sp3; with 1 electron in each of the 2sp3 orbitals to equal 6 electrons all up.

When bonded with hydrogen, do we count each of the 4x hydrogen electrons as belonging to the carbon like we do for the hydrogen (hydrogen wants to reach 2 electrons, so we count the carbon's electron as belonging to the hydrogen)? If so this would result in carbon having 10 electrons (1s2 = 2) + (2sp3 = 2) + (2sp3 = 2) + (2sp3 = 2) + (2sp3 = 2) = 10 all up despite the fact that it wants to have 8 electrons.

Could someone please point out where I'm going wrong here?

I have been following Khan Academy for revision and here is where I got the information that has confused me: https://youtu.be/u1eGSL6J6Fo?t=10m35s.

Comment: You don't count 1s2. These are deep down below and play no role.

Comment: The basic way to think about it that all those s- and p-elements want to have as much electrons in total, as noble gases do. 10 electrons in total is exactly non-bonded neon.

Comment: Thanks for that, exactly what I needed and suddenly it all makes sense again :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we want to specify the type of hybridization (***sp3, sp2, sp***) we count the number of regions with high electron density (bonds or lone pairs) and attribute it to the **valence sub-shells** such as ***2s*** and ***2p*** in the case of carbon. we can call ***s*** a sub-shell or orbital,  ***1s*** lies outside the valence shell so it is not considered in bonding.

So if we have 4 regions (bonds) as in methane they are made by the contribution of the four **orbitals** (***2s, 2px, 2py, 2pz***), while in case of ethene and ethyne (acetylene) the density regions are lesser than methane due to condensation of electron densities between carbons as double and triple bonds.

But still we have to mix from the 2 **sub-shell types of the valence shell**, ***S and P***, so we have ***sp2 and sp*** hybridizations, respectively. [image]

The electron density concentrates between the carbons in ethene and acetylene.

[image]

Comment: Please use bolding more sparingly. [See here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3921)